# UMVUE of Bernoulli random variables

Tags: bernoulli-distribution, sufficient-statistics, exponential-family, umvue

Let $X_1, X_2..... X_n$ be a random sample from a Bernoulli population with parameter $p$.

A sufficient statistic is $\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$. If we define
$$
U(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n)= \begin{cases}1/2n &\text{if }X_1+X_2=1 \cr
            0  &\text{otherwise}\cr
\end{cases}
$$
is an unbiased estimator of $p(1-p)/n$

Using Rao Backwell theorum,

$\delta(t)=$P(X1+X2=1/ $\sum_{i=1}^{n}$ Xi)

E($\delta(t)$)=p(1-p)/n

Then, $\delta(t)$ is UMVUE of p(1-p)/n.

Is this correct?

Comment: For a self-study question, you need to pursue the resolution of the question further than simply dropping a thought. For instance applying Rao-Blackwell should be within your reach since you have an unbiased estimator AND a sufficient statistic.

Comment: What I mean is that without further input from you it is not regular on this forum to provide full answers to self-study questions. I thus repeat my request that you produce more details on your attempt within the text of the question and not as additional comments.